# Symfony 3 - Collection of forms only sends data to one table

Tags: symfony, orm, webforms, doctrine

I am running Symfony 3.4 with 2 relevant entities - Entry and Track with a OneToMany relationship. I have been through [this arcticle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) - I am able to get an ArrayCollection to be added to the Entry table, but nothing is added to the Track table.

I have tried to exclude as much irrelevant code as possible for ease of reading.

**Entry**

```
<?php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`workshop_entry`")
 */
class Entry
{
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Track", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $tracklist;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->tracklist = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTracklist()
{
    return $this->tracklist;
}

public function addTrack(Track $track) {
    $this->tracklist->add($track);
}

public function removeTrack(Track $track) {
    $this->tracklist->removeElement($track);
}
}
```

**Track**

```
<?php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Track
 */
class Track
{
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $name;
```

**EntryType**

```
    class EntryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('tracklist', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => TrackType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
```

**EntryController**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $reviewEntry = new Entry();

        $form = $this->createForm(EntryType::class, $reviewEntry, ['action' => $request->getUri()]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        //Validates the form
        if($form->isValid())
            //
        $em->persist($reviewEntry);

        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:create.html.twig', ['form'=>$form->createView()]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@ORM\Entity` to your `Track` entity and run migrations

Comment: No luck unfortunately!